# Openstack PCI passthrough interface name error in Libvirt

Tags: openstack, libvirt

I want to start an instance on *openstack* pike with **SRIOV** enabled NICs. However, I am getting a Libvirt error regarding the node name. The error looks weird as the node name is not matching the interface name on the host machine or in the configuration files.

> 2018-01-28 20:40:11.416 2953 ERROR nova.compute.manager [req-caa92f1d-5ac1-402d-a8bc-b08ab350a21f - - - - -] Error updating resources for node jupiter.: libvirtError: Node device not found: no node device with matching name 'net_enp129s2_b2_87_6e_13_a1_5e'
>   2018-01-28 20:40:11.416 2953 ERROR nova.compute.manager Traceback (most recent call last):
>   2018-01-28 20:40:11.416 2953 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 6696, in update_available_resource_for_node
>   2018-01-28 20:40:11.416 2953 ERROR nova.compute.manager     rt.update_available_resource(context, nodename)
>   2018-01-28 20:40:11.416 2953 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/resource_tracker.py", line 641, in update_available_resource
>   2018-01-28 20:40:11.416 2953 ERROR nova.compute.manager     resources = self.driver.get_available_resource(nodename)
>   2018-01-28 20:40:11.416 2953 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 5857, in get_available_resource
>   2018-01-28 20:40:11.416 2953 ERROR nova.compute.manager
>   2018-01-28 20:40:11.416 2953 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 5621, in _get_pci_passthrough_devices
>   2018-01-28 20:40:11.416 2953 ERROR nova.compute.manager     for name in dev_names:
>   2018-01-28 20:40:11.416 2953 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 5582, in _get_pcidev_info
>   2018-01-28 20:40:11.416 2953 ERROR nova.compute.manager     device['label'] = 'label_%(vendor_id)s_%(product_id)s' % device
>   2018-01-28 20:40:11.416 2953 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 5553, in _get_device_capabilities
>   2018-01-28 20:40:11.416 2953 ERROR nova.compute.manager     pcinet_info = self._get_pcinet_info(address)
>   2018-01-28 20:40:11.416 2953 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 5496, in _get_pcinet_info
>   2018-01-28 20:40:11.416 2953 ERROR nova.compute.manager     virtdev = self._host.device_lookup_by_name(devname)
>   2018-01-28 20:40:11.416 2953 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/host.py", line 845, in device_lookup_by_name
>   2018-01-28 20:40:11.416 2953 ERROR nova.compute.manager     return self.get_connection().nodeDeviceLookupByName(name)
>   2018-01-28 20:40:11.416 2953 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/tpool.py", line 186, in doit
>   2018-01-28 20:40:11.416 2953 ERROR nova.compute.manager     result = proxy_call(self._autowrap, f, *args, **kwargs)
>   2018-01-28 20:40:11.416 2953 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/tpool.py", line 144, in proxy_call
>   2018-01-28 20:40:11.416 2953 ERROR nova.compute.manager     rv = execute(f, *args, **kwargs)
>   2018-01-28 20:40:11.416 2953 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/tpool.py", line 125, in execute
>   2018-01-28 20:40:11.416 2953 ERROR nova.compute.manager     six.reraise(c, e, tb)
>   2018-01-28 20:40:11.416 2953 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/tpool.py", line 83, in tworker
>   2018-01-28 20:40:11.416 2953 ERROR nova.compute.manager     rv = meth(*args, **kwargs)
>   2018-01-28 20:40:11.416 2953 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 4177, in nodeDeviceLookupByName
>   2018-01-28 20:40:11.416 2953 ERROR nova.compute.manager     if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virNodeDeviceLookupByName() failed', conn=self)
>   2018-01-28 20:40:11.416 2953 ERROR nova.compute.manager libvirtError: Node device not found: no node device with matching name 'net_enp129s2_b2_87_6e_13_a1_5e'
>   2018-01-28 20:40:11.416 2953 ERROR nova.compute.manager

The correct interface name is enp129s0f0. However, I am getting the node name as net_enp129s2_b2_87_6e_13_a1_5e' which i believe is the reason behind the failure of vm creation on openstack. Please if someone could help me understand how the node name is passed on to the Libvirt from openstack or how can I resolve this issue.